# set Time zone on windows xp

Tags: command-line, windows-xp

What single command (for use in a batch file) will change the PC's
time zone to GMT+10

Is there a line command which will do this directly?

---

I have started to look at the "Time And Date" control panel but it
doesn't quite do what I want ...

The following command opens the "Time And Date" control panel and
selects the time zone tab. But what do I do to automatically select
the GMT+10 setting and then close the control panel?

rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL timedate.cpl,,1

Answer (score 2):

Use this for Windows XP:

`runDLL32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL timedate.cpl,,/Z (GMT+10:00) Brisbane`

Or this for Windows 7:

`TZUTIL /S "E. Australia Standard Time"`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that Powershell CMD-lets can solve your problem. Here you can get more information about it: [Technet Support](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176960.aspx)